# Javascript/PHP/HTML: Disabling respective textbox on unchecked checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox, textbox

This is my current code that I'm working with. I want to disable the textbox on its unchecked checkbox but I cannot seem to get it to work. Please advise. Javascript/Jquery is fine as well, I can work around them.

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
echo '<td width="200px"><input name="prodID[i]" id="'.$row['prodID'].'" type="checkbox" value="'.$row['prodID'].'" onclick="document.getElementsByName(prodQty[i]).disabled=this.checked;"> '; 
echo $row['prodID'].'&nbsp';        
echo '<input name="prodQty[i]" id="'.$row['prodID'].'" type="text" size="1">';
```

Comment: you have written wrong like  `document.getElementByName(prodQty[i]).disabled`    you should write like    `document.getElemenstByName(prodQty[i]).disabled`    as it selects returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified name

Comment: Taking into consideration your accidental typo of Elements, I tried your solution but nothing came up still. @Abbas

Comment: you are using same id for checkbox and text field....please resolve this first as same id's for different entities not allowed.....you can use like `check_$row['prodID']`  means append your ID with some text..

Answer (score 0):

you can call function like

```
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
echo '<td width="200px"><input name="check_<?php echo $row['prodID']; ?>" id="check_<?php echo $row['prodID']; ?>" type="checkbox" value="check_<?php echo $row['prodID']; ?>" onclick='document.getElementById("text_<?php echo $row['prodQty']; ?>").disabled=this.checked'> 
echo $row['prodID'].'&nbsp';        
echo '<input name="text_<?php echo $row['prodQty']; ?>" id="text_<?php echo $row['prodQty']; ?>" type="text" size="1">';
```

As you can see i have appended Id's with `check` and `text` like words so that to differentiate name and id's.

Hope this might work.

Let me know if there is any issue.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for helping me out, I didn't quite grasp what you meant by appending ID with some text until now. The error is now: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'check_' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' @Abbas I checked the syntax alr

Comment: I also went to google on string concatenation in PHP and it seems that . is used instead of +? I tried using . but it still doesn't work, kindly advise. @Abbas

Comment: see my updated answer and let me know about what issues you are facing...now it won't give any error....